# How to add revision comment when making change through Rally WSAPI?

Tags: rally

When editing a Rally object through its web UI, I can put a comment in the "Change Description" entry field at the bottom of the form, and that description will appear alongside my changes in the revision history for the object.

How can I do the same thing when changing a Rally object through its web services API?
What additional URL parameter or payload attribute can be used to specify a change description for the changes being made in an API call?

Forgive me if I'm blind, but I can't find this anywhere in the WSAPI documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Revision object in the [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) that has Description attribute.
This Description made up of two parts: the actual Description of a revision generated by Rally, which is read only both in UI and WS API, and the text entered by a user in the "Change Description" box on the Edit page of artifact that is being edited.

It is not possible to create the "Change Description" user input part of the Revision object when an artifact is updated via WS API because in order to allow that WS API would have to allow a creation of Revision object via WS API, since the "Change Description" is a part of Revision object, and not the actual artifact that is being updated via WS API.

When I update a story via API I do not create a new Revision object with my code.
Revision object is created by the system as a result of the story update that I post.

Comment: As a workaround you could mimic this functionality by creating a hidden custom field called ChangeDescription, and then each time you update an artifact via WSAPI also update the value of that field with a logical changeset summary.